# Where should I go to research this error message?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos6.2

Working to get a CentOS / Apache / PHP stack running...
At this point, I have SSH access, and in the Bash, can use php to do simple math; so I know the php is on the machine and working, (sorta).  Also, Apache must be okay; I can stop and start it and just the fact I can get to my ip and use bash says it's ON, I deduce.  Finally to the moment.

When I navigate to the server over the internet, no website!  But,in the php error log, I get an error message very similair to this, one for each module in the php package:

`[12-Aug-2012 18:34:53] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/etc/php.d/curl.so' - /etc/php.d/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

Sure would be good to recieve a hint where to look next.

Comment: I am constantly amazed at the sharing worldwide.  Thanks for your responses fellas, it'll take me a couple hours, and in the last half hour I finally found a few pointers via google; but I will work with your replies first!!!

Comment: Okay, all the .ini files are in /etc/php.d, but this:[root@bryanserver php.d]# php -i |grep extension
extension_dir => /etc/php.d => /etc/php.d    seems like it is wrong.  Going as fast as this noob can...  :)

Comment: Okay, from a tip from Google, this *find* verified file is ON the server:
[root@bryanserver etc]# find / -name curl.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so
[root@bryanserver etc]#  and sure enough I confirmed that, looked it up down in /usr/...  and did a get to my notebook; yep it's a file with all those funny characters, so all 20 php .so files are in the usual place, now back to sorting the path issues; oh, the ini files all seem to be patterned after the curl.ini I inspected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On CentOS, by default, the PHP extension directory is set to `/usr/lib(64)/php/modules`:

```
# php -i | grep extension
extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/modules => /usr/lib64/php/modules
```

and the curl extension is configured in:

```
# cat /etc/php.d/curl.ini 
; Enable curl extension module
extension=curl.so
```

If your PHP is compiled from source, make sure that cURL is enabled with `--with-curl[=DIR]`. If PHP was installed via `yum`, I suspect that someone is loading the cURL with wrong absolute path `/etc/php.d/curl.so`. You can find out by following command:

```
# grep -lr curl /etc/php.ini /etc/php.d/
```

Change to the relative path and restart Apache to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for that help.  I wouldn't have known what to look for without all those areas being identified.  It was the php.ini file; there had been nothing defined in it for extension-dir, and extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules" got php working without the error mssgs which kicked off this question.

Answer (score 1):

You should confirm that the file (/etc/php.d/curl.so) is not there.  Then, consider either rebuilding the package that provides it, or the package that needs it.  Alternatively, just use locate to find it on the machine, and create a symlink from the path mentioned in the error to the actual library.

The message itself is fairly self-explanatory - PHP needed the CURL library, and didn't find it where it was expected.

Comment: As it turned out, that would have been the first step, and as noted, they were not in that location. Thanks, cheers.

Answer (score -1):

PHP curl library is part of php-common common package. As quanta responded above, follow those steps to resolve your error.

If you are compiling from source, ensure curl-devel is installed.

Comment: Why did my response get a down vote? May I ask?

Comment: curl was built into PHP by default. AFAIK, there is no such package on the CentOS.

Comment: quanta, I just checked on my centos and my original command yum install php-curl. When run, centos actually attempts to get php-common in which curl is built in. So, technically the command works. Just FYI.